# RexProScriptException transaction is not open in Django with Titan (graph DB)

Tags: python, django, gremlin, titan, rexster

I am stuck with my TitanDB, Django1.8 and Mogwai0.7.7 package.
I have Graph database titan/cassandra on localhost dev machine, and after creating wrong queries in rexster gremlin web interface my Django Object Graph Mapper mogwai stopped working. Titan is still working and data is present but Django stopped working with it.

```
File "/Users/x/envs/graph/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rexpro/connectors/base.py", line 281, in close_transaction
    raise exceptions.RexProScriptException("transaction is not open")
RexProScriptException: transaction is not open.
```

After googling, I found [this bitbucked fix](https://bitbucket.org/wellaware/mogwai/pull-requests/14/close-a-connection-during-a-exception-and/diff)
But I don't know how to apply it. Maybe doing a lib update with pip...

Comment: Who wants bounty? No one can help?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323035/how-to-execute-gremlin-query-with-mogwai/35340818#35340818

Answer (score 1):

you might need to check django atomic transacion and recheck how package handling transaction for db connection.